# Necessary and sufficient condition for $X_n/n\rightarrow0$ almost surely when $(X_n)$ is i.i.d.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a i.i.d. sequence of random variables. My question is how to find a necessary and sufficient condition for $X_n/n\rightarrow0$ a.s.

First, I assume that $EX_i^p<\infty$, $p>1$. Then by Chebyshev's inequality and Borel-Cantelli lemma, $X_n/n\rightarrow0$ a.s. Is true that $X_n/n\rightarrow0$ a.s. imply $EX_i^p<\infty$ for all $p>1$ ?

Comment: "First, I assume that $EX_i^p<\infty$, $p>1$. Then by Chebyshev's inequality and Borel-Cantelli lemma, $X_n/n\rightarrow0$ a.s." You should definitely show how you prove this part.

Comment: To be clear, the exercise asks you to rediscover that $X_n/n\to0$ almost surely if and only if $X_1$ is integrable.

Comment: Use Borel Cantelli.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is any sequence of random variables such that there are finite constants $p>1$, $D\geq 0$ for which $E[|X_i|^p] \leq D$ for all $i$, then indeed $X_i/i\rightarrow 0$ with probability 1 (for the reason stated in the question).  There is no need for iid assumptions.

On the other hand, if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with a finite mean $E[X]$ (so $E[|X|]<\infty$) then from the strong law of large numbers we know $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \rightarrow E[X]$ with prob 1.  You can show this means that $X_n/n \rightarrow 0$ with prob 1 (even if $E[X^2]=\infty$).

Comment: So, in other words: No.  It is not true that $X_n/n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely implies $E[|X_i|^p]<\infty$ for all $p>1$.